# Scroll com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento

Estou criando um site, e estou querendo fazer um efeito de scroll nas páginas onde ao clicar no  item do menu a pagina role até onde esta as informações relacionadas.

Seria mais ou menos igual a esse, porém um pouco mais simples apenas com a rolagem mesmo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: No futuro coloque por favor código na pergunta, para podermos responder com detalhe ao problema que tem.

Comment: Robson, as respostas foram corretas para o problema que tinhas?

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa de ter no menu alguma indicação do alvo para o scroll.

Pode ser o `id` do elemento guardado numa propriedade `data`, um href/ancora ou outro. Se usar uma ancora (`<a>`) pode precisar de usar o `.preventDefault()` para impedir o link de ser seguido (nalguns casos quer mesmo que o link fique no url, então não deve usar).

Depois tem de interceptar o click pode usar o jQuery .anymate() para fazer o scroll, indo buscar a posição desse elemento como alvo.

Exemplo de HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div data-destino="parte1">Parte 1</div>
    <div data-destino="parte2">Parte 2</div>
</div>
<div id="parte1"></div>
<div id="parte2"></div>
```

Exemplo de jQuery

```
$('.menu div').on('click', function () {
    var destino = '#' + $(this).data('destino');
    var posicaoDestino = $(destino).position().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: posicaoDestino
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/zc966/**

Comment: Eu ia responder praticamente o mesmo :) http://jsfiddle.net/QaK3P/

Comment: @bfavaretto :) Mas já agora, junte a sua resposta pois você usa ancoras e eu não

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o `href` dos links:

```
<a href="#Id_da_div"> link </a>
```

Ex:

```
<a href="#contato">Fale Conosco</a>
<script>
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    var destino = $(this).attr('href');
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(destino).position().top}, 600);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Para alterar a velocidade do *scroll*, altere o último parametro de `600` para o valor desejado. O valor é em milisegundos, ou  `"slow"`, `"mid"`, `"fast"`.

Comment: Oi, user8993, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Confira o guia do editor http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help, e leia [answer], é legal explicar ***porque*** seu código resolve o problema. Compare com a resposta do Sergio aí em cima,  ele tem essa quantidade de pontos *por algum motivo*... ;)

Comment: Che, que *upgrade* legal! +1+

Answer (score 0):

Oi, você pode usar o scrollTop em JQuery.

Tenta isso **(FUNCIONANDO)**

```
$("#elemento1").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop' : $("#elemento2").position().top }, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar ANCHOR.

Link a ser clicado

```
<a href="#vemPraCa">Clique aqui para dar Scroll</a>
```

Lugar aonde o Scroll vai

```
<a name="vemPraCa"></a>
```